# How to fetch rows from a table based on limit (eg from rows 5 to 50 order by somecolumn) in oracle 7 release

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, oracle8i

I have two databases.
1. Oracle
2. SQL Server

Both have the same table `TABLE`. I have to fetch data in limits, order by some columns, in both the table and validate it (against each other).
Suppose the limit is 100 to 150

For SQL I am using

```
select * 
from (
    select row_number() over (order by specific_column) as row, *  
    from  Table
) as t
where row between 100 and 150
```

For Oracle I am using

```
select * 
from (
      select columnname, rownum r 
      from Table
 ) a where a.r>=100 and a.r<=150 order by specific_column
```

But the results I am getting is entirely different in each output.

May be the orderby is working first in sqlserver and then its fetching it by rownum, and vice versa in oracle.

PS: Please note that, the version of oracle what I am using is 7.3.x and order by in subquery is not supported.

Comment: I think you can use the first query for both databases. (http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=102)

Comment: No, its not working, Inavlid Function for row_number(). May be because of the older version of oracle

Comment: In oracle when you call select columnname, rownum r from Table you don't order by specific_column. Shouldn't you use ordering there as well?

Comment: @EtibarHəsənov : Order by is not working there, I guess it doesn't  work in subqueries. Missing right parenthesis error is what its coming if I am using order by in subquery

Comment: @Justin Cave : This question is not duplicate. There is only a query in oracle, but I want an equivalent query in sql server in particular order by. Please provide the solution and untag it from duplicate

Comment: @Abhii - Your SQL Server query appears to be functionally correct (assuming a recent enough version of SQL Server).  I can't mark a question as a duplicate of multiple other questions-- there are plenty of SQL Server pagination questions on StackOverflow that takl about this.

Comment: @JustinCave - I agree that there are many answers in portal regarding SQL pagination. But my problem is pagination in SQL and Oracle are retrieving different result set and I am expecting answer for that. If you can untag from duplicate, i may get more answers

Comment: @Abhii - There is no way to untag a duplicate.  I believe the problem is that your Oracle query is functionally incorrect.  That's why I closed it as a duplicate of the Oracle question that has a correct version of a pagination query.

Comment: @JustinCave I have tried that solution, Error : ORA:00907 Missing Right Parenthesis, this error is coming, anytime I am using order by in subquery.
Please consider, oracle 8.x it is.

If I am removing order by clause from subquery, then its working fine.
But I need to use it with order by clause.

Comment: Exactly what version of Oracle are you using?  8.x could mean anything from 8.0.3 to 8.1.7.  That's a huge number of releases.  Of course, all of them have been desupported for at least the better part of a decade.  If you are using 8.0.x, you probably can't do this in a single SQL statement https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:127412348064#12379480725590

Comment: @JustinCave : Its 8i I guess or ora81

Comment: If you are using 8i, then you're using 8.1.x.  If you are using 8.1.x, the `rownum` pagination query in the duplicate thread will work.  But don't guess, get the actual version.  Query `v$version` if you don't know.

Comment: @JustinCave : Sir its oracle 7 server release 7.3.4.4.1 - Production

Comment: Then you're out of luck.  You can't do it in a SQL statement.  You'd need procedural logic.  Oracle 7 has been desupported for almost 20 years.

Comment: @JustinCave Can you please provide me that PL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78692/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-abhii).